# Python TKinter - Retrieve all the ID of all elements in my canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How will I retrieve all the tag ID's of all the elements in my canvas Python Tkinter? ANy help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "tag ID's"? tags and ids are two different things. Do you want the id of every element in the canvas, or a list of tags, or something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley -- I just want the id of every element in the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

To get the id of all of the elements on a canvas, use the `find_all` method:

```
id_list = the_canvas.find_all()
```